# I do select on sql and create new columns based on what I want to lookup inside of it and add another column with looked up answers

Tags: sql-server

I need to make sql command work, thing is next
I have a table, from where I do make sql select,
during select I create 2 additional columns (rem_day and prev_day)
I want to add another column during that selection which will be result
of lookuped value to find prev_day 'summary' value for each rem_day

I tried joins but failed with it

query:

```
SELECT unique_id, branch_id, branch_name, type + ' ' + class typeclass, sum(pistol_data) summary, tr_date, date, 
convert(varchar, branch_id, 0) + type + ' ' + class + ' ' + convert(varchar, tr_date, 101) rem_day, 
convert(varchar, branch_id, 0) + type + ' ' + class + ' ' + convert(varchar, tr_date - 1, 101) prev_day 
FROM golden_oil.dbo.transactions WHERE deleted = 0 and description = 1 
GROUP BY unique_id, branch_id, branch_name, type, class, tr_date, date ORDER BY tr_date DESC, branch_id ASC
```

table:

```
USE [golden_oil]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[transactions](
    [unique_id] [int] NULL,
    [branch_id] [int] NULL,
    [branch_name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [username] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [tank_id] [int] NULL,
    [type] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [class] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [pistol_name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [pistol_data] [float] NULL,
    [adjustment] [numeric](7, 5) NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NULL,
    [deleted] [bit] NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [multiplier] [int] NULL,
    [tr_date] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

sample data:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (1,1,'test','test',1,'Dizeli',NULL,'Dizeli:_1',7331.87,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/22/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (1,1,'test','test',1,'Dizeli',NULL,'Dizeli:_2',134804.57,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/22/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (1,1,'test','test',1,'Dizeli',NULL,'Dizeli:_3',167585.77,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/22/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (1,1,'test','test',1,'Dizeli',NULL,'Dizeli:_4',269361.97,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/22/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (1,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_2',5154.42,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/22/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (1,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_1',12762.88,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/22/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (1,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_4',47979.9,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/22/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (1,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_8',122833.33,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/22/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (1,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_5',126579.4,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/22/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (1,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_3',133036.77,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/22/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (1,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_7',234392.17,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/22/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (1,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_6',293191.89,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/22/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (1,1,'test','test',3,'Benzini','Premiumi','Benzini:Premiumi_1',1361.75,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/22/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (1,1,'test','test',3,'Benzini','Premiumi','Benzini:Premiumi_2',27410.16,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/22/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (1,1,'test','test',3,'Benzini','Premiumi','Benzini:Premiumi_4',43258.11,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/22/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (1,1,'test','test',3,'Benzini','Premiumi','Benzini:Premiumi_3',43588.9,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/22/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (2,1,'test','test',1,'Dizeli',NULL,'Dizeli:_1',7712.23,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/23/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (2,1,'test','test',1,'Dizeli',NULL,'Dizeli:_2',135219.57,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/23/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (2,1,'test','test',1,'Dizeli',NULL,'Dizeli:_3',167928.19,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/23/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (2,1,'test','test',1,'Dizeli',NULL,'Dizeli:_4',269674.97,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/23/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (2,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_2',5355.27,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/23/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (2,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_1',13361.86,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/23/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (2,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_4',48301.26,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/23/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (2,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_8',123368.18,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/23/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (2,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_5',127209.37,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/23/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (2,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_3',133207.91,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/23/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (2,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_7',235021.41,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/23/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (2,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_6',294159.17,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/23/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (2,1,'test','test',3,'Benzini','Premiumi','Benzini:Premiumi_1',1361.75,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/23/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (2,1,'test','test',3,'Benzini','Premiumi','Benzini:Premiumi_2',27410.16,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/23/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (2,1,'test','test',3,'Benzini','Premiumi','Benzini:Premiumi_4',43258.11,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/23/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (2,1,'test','test',3,'Benzini','Premiumi','Benzini:Premiumi_3',43588.9,0,'7/24/2019',0,1,-1,'7/23/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (7,1,'test','test',1,'Dizeli',NULL,'Dizeli:_1',7759.06,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/24/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (7,1,'test','test',1,'Dizeli',NULL,'Dizeli:_2',135799.31,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/24/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (7,1,'test','test',1,'Dizeli',NULL,'Dizeli:_3',168210.16,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/24/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (7,1,'test','test',1,'Dizeli',NULL,'Dizeli:_4',270682.61,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/24/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (7,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_2',5730.7,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/24/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (7,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_1',13676.06,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/24/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (7,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_4',48732.65,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/24/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (7,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_8',123741.67,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/24/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (7,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_5',127708.61,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/24/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (7,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_3',133428,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/24/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (7,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_7',235559.97,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/24/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (7,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_6',294871.09,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/24/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (7,1,'test','test',3,'Benzini','Premiumi','Benzini:Premiumi_1',1361.75,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/24/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (7,1,'test','test',3,'Benzini','Premiumi','Benzini:Premiumi_2',27410.16,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/24/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (7,1,'test','test',3,'Benzini','Premiumi','Benzini:Premiumi_4',43258.11,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/24/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (7,1,'test','test',3,'Benzini','Premiumi','Benzini:Premiumi_3',43588.9,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/24/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (8,1,'test','test',1,'Dizeli',NULL,'Dizeli:_1',7969.62,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/25/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (8,1,'test','test',1,'Dizeli',NULL,'Dizeli:_2',136254.58,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/25/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (8,1,'test','test',1,'Dizeli',NULL,'Dizeli:_3',168373.9,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/25/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (8,1,'test','test',1,'Dizeli',NULL,'Dizeli:_4',271264.41,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/25/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (8,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_2',6365.51,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/25/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (8,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_1',13821.18,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/25/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (8,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_4',48748.4,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/25/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (8,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_8',123884.81,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/25/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (8,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_5',127981.33,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/25/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (8,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_3',133745.19,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/25/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (8,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_7',236539.28,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/25/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (8,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari_6',295695.87,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/25/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (8,1,'test','test',3,'Benzini','Premiumi','Benzini:Premiumi_1',1361.75,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/25/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (8,1,'test','test',3,'Benzini','Premiumi','Benzini:Premiumi_2',27410.16,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/25/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (8,1,'test','test',3,'Benzini','Premiumi','Benzini:Premiumi_4',43258.11,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/25/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (8,1,'test','test',3,'Benzini','Premiumi','Benzini:Premiumi_3',43588.9,0,'7/25/2019',0,1,-1,'7/25/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (9,1,'test','test',1,'Dizeli',NULL,'Dizeli: Migeba',6000,0,'7/25/2019',0,4,1,'7/25/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (12,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari Sacdeli Chamosxma',20,0,'7/25/2019',0,2,-1,'7/25/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (12,1,'test','test',2,'Benzini','Regulari','Benzini:Regulari Chabruneba',20,0,'7/25/2019',0,3,1,'7/25/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (12,1,'test','test',3,'Benzini','Premiumi','Benzini:Premiumi Sacdeli Chamosxma',30,0,'7/25/2019',0,2,-1,'7/25/2019');
INSERT INTO dbo.transactions(unique_id,branch_id,branch_name,username,tank_id,type,class,pistol_name,pistol_data,adjustment,date,deleted,description,multiplier,tr_date) VALUES (12,1,'test','test',3,'Benzini','Premiumi','Benzini:Premiumi Chabruneba',30,0,'7/25/2019',0,3,1,'7/25/2019');
```

Comment: Please don't use non sql terms (vlookup) in sql questions - And I have amended the tags since this is clearly sqlserver code.

Comment: Please don't paste a link and expect the volunteers here to download a file from a complete stranger. If you want to supply data, include it as DDL and DML statements in your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create procedure which did everything between table variables, not best solution though as I have created multiple tables but will tweak it from time to time to improve

```
USE [golden_oil]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[pistols]    Script Date: 7/27/2019 4:30:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pistols] 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @PistolData TABLE
(
    unique_id int NULL,
    branch_id int NULL,
    branch_name nvarchar(max) NULL,
    tank_id int NULL,
    typeclass varchar(max) NULL,
    summary float NULL,
    tr_date datetime null,
    date datetime null,
    rem_day varchar(max),
    prev_day varchar(max)
)

    DECLARE @SecondData TABLE
(
    unique_id int NULL,
    branch_id int NULL,
    branch_name nvarchar(max) NULL,
    tank_id int NULL,
    typeclass varchar(max) NULL,
    summary float NULL,
    tr_date datetime null,
    date datetime null,
    rem_day varchar(max),
    prev_day varchar(max)
)

    DECLARE @ThirdTable TABLE
(
    unique_id int NULL,
    branch_id int NULL,
    branch_name nvarchar(max) NULL,
    tank_id int NULL,
    typeclass varchar(max) NULL,
    summary float NULL,
    tr_date datetime null,
    date datetime null,
    rem_day varchar(max),
    prev_day varchar(max),
    matching_day varchar(max),
    matching_summary float
)

    DECLARE @FinalTable TABLE
(
    unique_id int NULL,
    branch_id int NULL,
    branch_name nvarchar(max) NULL,
    tank_id int NULL,
    typeclass varchar(max) NULL,
    tr_date datetime null,
    date datetime null,
    matching_summary float
)


DECLARE @LastTable TABLE
(
    unique_id int NULL,
    branch_name nvarchar(max) NULL,
    tr_date datetime null,
    date datetime null
)


INSERT INTO @PistolData (unique_id, branch_id, branch_name, tank_id, typeclass, summary, tr_date, date, rem_day, prev_day)
SELECT unique_id, branch_id, branch_name, tank_id, type + ' ' + class typeclass, sum(pistol_data) summary, tr_date, date, 
convert(varchar, branch_id, 0) + type + ' ' + class + ' ' + convert(varchar, tr_date, 101) rem_day, 
convert(varchar, branch_id, 0) + type + ' ' + class + ' ' + convert(varchar, tr_date - 1, 101) prev_day 
FROM golden_oil.dbo.transactions WHERE deleted = 0 and description = 1 
GROUP BY unique_id, branch_id, branch_name, tank_id, type, class, tr_date, date ORDER BY tr_date DESC, branch_id ASC

INSERT @SecondData(unique_id, branch_id, branch_name, tank_id, typeclass, summary, tr_date, date, rem_day, prev_day) 
SELECT unique_id, branch_id, branch_name, tank_id, typeclass, summary, tr_date, date, rem_day, prev_day FROM @PistolData

INSERT @ThirdTable(unique_id, branch_id, branch_name, tank_id, typeclass, summary, tr_date, date, rem_day, prev_day, matching_day, matching_summary)
SELECT unique_id, branch_id, branch_name, tank_id, typeclass, summary, tr_date, date, rem_day, prev_day, [matching_day], [matching_summary]
FROM @PistolData as pd
LEFT JOIN (SELECT rem_day as [matching_day], summary as [matching_summary] FROM @SecondData) as sd ON pd.prev_day = [matching_day]

UPDATE @ThirdTable SET matching_summary = summary - matching_summary

INSERT @FinalTable(unique_id, branch_id, branch_name, tank_id, typeclass, tr_date, date, matching_summary)
SELECT unique_id, branch_id, branch_name, tank_id, typeclass, tr_date, date, matching_summary FROM @ThirdTable




INSERT @LastTable(unique_id, branch_name, tr_date, date)
SELECT Distinct(unique_id), branch_name, tr_date, date FROM @FinalTable


SELECT unique_id, branch_name, tr_date, date, [dizeli], [regulari], [premiumi] FROM @LastTable as lt
LEFT JOIN (SELECT typeclass as matchvaldiz, tr_date as diz_date, branch_name as diz_name, matching_summary as [dizeli] FROM @FinalTable) as diz ON matchvaldiz = 'Dizeli ' and diz_name = branch_name and tr_date = diz_date
LEFT JOIN (SELECT typeclass as matchvalreg, tr_date as reg_date, branch_name as reg_name, matching_summary as [regulari] FROM @FinalTable) as reg ON matchvalreg = 'Benzini Regulari'  and reg_name = branch_name and tr_date = reg_date
LEFT JOIN (SELECT typeclass as matchvalprem, tr_date as prem_date, branch_name as prem_name, matching_summary as [premiumi] FROM @FinalTable) as prem ON matchvalprem = 'Benzini Premiumi' and prem_name = branch_name and tr_date = prem_date
ORDER BY tr_date DESC, branch_name ASC
END
```